Does this chordal graph-preserving operation also preserve perfect graphs?
Assume that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are two graphs containing complete subgraphs $H_1$ and $H_2$, respectively, of the same order and $G_3$ is the graph obtained by identifying the vertices of $H_1$ with the vertices of $H_2$ (in a one-to-one manner). Here is an example:  $H_1$ and $H_2$ are triangles with green color.


A chordal graph is one where every cycle of four or more vertices has a chord, an edge connecting non-adjacent vertices of the cycle.
A perfect graph is a graph $G$ such that for every induced subgraph of $G$, the clique number equals the chromatic number.

The theorem below can be located on page 167 of the second edition of Chartrand and Zhang's book, Chromatic Graph Theory.
Theorem 1 Let $G$ be a graph obtained by identifying two complete subgraphs of the same order in two graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$. Then $G$ is chordal if and only if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are chordal.
A classic result states that chordal graphs are perfect graphs. So now, I am trying to determine if changing the conditions of Theorem 1 from chordal graphs to perfect graphs would still hold.
Problem:  Let $G$ be a graph obtained by identifying two complete subgraphs of the same order in two graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$. Then $G$ is perfect if and only if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are perfect.

In the above problem, $G$ is perfect, and obviously $G_1$ and $G_2$
are its induced subgraphs and therefore also perfect. However, I am
still not clear about the converse. I vaguely feel that strong
perfect graph theorem, which states that a graph is perfect if and
only if it has no induced odd cycles of length five or more, or their
complements, might apply.


This seems like (at least a variation of) the clique sum:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique-sum

Your claim is correct.
Indeed, you can use the strong perfect graph theorem for the converse direction:
Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be perfect and let $G$ be defined as given in the claim. Assume that $G$ is not perfect. Then $G$ must have an induced $K_{2k+1}$ ("odd hole") or induced $\overline{K_{2k+1}}$ ("odd anti-hole") for some $k \geq 2$.
If the former is the case, let's call the odd hole is $F$. We claim that there cannot be $u,v \in V(F)$ such that $u \in V(G_1) \setminus V(G_2)$ and $v \in V(G_2) \setminus V(G_1)$. Indeed, if such $u,v$ existed, then $F$ induces two internally vertex-disjoint $u$-$v$-paths. Those paths must intersect $V(G_1 \cap G_2)$ in different vertices $w_u, w_v$. However, as $G_1 \cap G_2$ is complete, we have that $w_u w_v$ is an edge in $G$. Hence, $F$ is not actually induced, a contradiction. So, we either have $V(F) \subseteq V(G_1)$ or $V(F) \subseteq V(G_2)$.
Now, for the other case, you just need to consider the complement and a similar type of argument. For that, observe that the complement of $G_1 \cap G_2$ is empty (i.e. with no edges).

I'm confused about the last paragraph. (Your last paragraph is also where I'm having trouble thinking about the problem before.) I have a feeling that the complements of $G_3$ might produce an odd hole of length at least 5.  The hole uses partly the vertices of $\overline {G_1}$ and partly the vertices of $\overline {G_2}$. I have no restructuring reason to prove that they don't exist, even though the complement of $G_1\cap G_2$ is an independent set. I think I might be wrong somewhere.

I see. Any vertices chosen from $\overline{G_3}[V(G_1-H)]$ and $\overline{G_3}[V(G_2-H)]$ are connected by edges in $\overline{G_3}$. Furthermore, any odd hole of length at least 5 does not produce in $ \overline{G_3}$
